# Clean Magento2 Cache with Capistrano on multiple server

Tags: magento2

I'm using Capistrano to deploy magento2 on multiple instances. 
The deploy works well. I'd like to use an extra command like:

```
cap production magento:cache:clean
```

But the cache is cleared just on one server.

Any suggestion on what I'd have to check?
Thank you

Comment: Is the deployment for a single M2 installation split amongst multiple servers? i.e. do they all share the same database?

Comment: Yes, single M2 installation sharaing same db and a nsf for media.

Answer (score 1):

Have you got a shared cache set up? i.e. do the `var/cache/` folders share via NFS? Or do you use a solution like Redis for caching?

If you haven't already, I would 100% recommend installing Redis to a server and having each of your instances communicate to it for backend caching. This way when you call `magento:cache:flush` via Capistrano on a single instance, it'll flush the cache for them all.

For more info on getting that set up, see the Magento dev docs here: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/config-guide/redis/config-redis.html